# AWS + Tomcat 8 + VRaptor 4: após aumentar o volume da instância, app não starta

Tags: tomcat, amazon-aws, vraptor

Boa tarde!

Temos uma aplicação rodando na Amazon e estava tudo funcionando perfeitamente até ontem.

Tivemos de trocar o volume da instância pois o antigo havia atingido 100% da sua capacidade... Para isto, realizei todos os passos no tutorial da própria Amazon... Temos um outro app rodando em PHP e aquele voltou a operar normalmente após a troca de volume...

Nos logs do Tomcat, está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
16-Sep-2015 17:30:44.925 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
 org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.checkForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer.addClasses(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createClasses(BeanDeployment.java:209)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:328)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2231)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3979)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3983)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4871)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:80)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadAnnotatedType(BeanDeployer.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:1057)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.ClassScope.computeEnclosingScope(ClassScope.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.getEnclosingScope(AbstractScope.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.findTypeVariable(CoreReflectionFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitTypeVariableSignature(Reifier.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature.accept(TypeVariableSignature.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.<init>(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.of(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:193)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:80)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3559)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2349)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2312)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2227)
    ... 17 more

16-Sep-2015 17:30:45.012 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextDestroyed(WeldInitialListener.java:120)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.api.helpers.ForwardingServletListener.contextDestroyed(ForwardingServletListener.java:30)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextDestroyed(Listener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Já segui vários tutoriais, tentei alterar as configuração do app(context, beans, pom), alterar versão da próprio Weld e nada...

Alguém pode dar uma luz ?

Obrigado, abraços!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos, encontrei o problema.

A biblioteca Guava estava conflitando através das dependências que eu havia instalado... Para verificar isto, executei um `mvn dependency:tree` e adicionei-a nas tags exclude.

Abraços!